# configure WebLogic to accept HEAD request

Tags: svg, weblogic, head

I am maintaining an enterprise web application that require to display SVG on various browsers. When testing on different deployed servers (Websphere, Weblogic), we found out IE10/11 will issue a HEAD request before GET request the actual svg content.

```
  <object data="testSVG.svg" type="image/svg+xml"
      width="1250" height="750" id="mySVGObject">
    <h1>Put optional fallback content here</h1>
  </object>
```

IE10/11 will send a HEAD request for testSVG.svg before GET request for testSVG.svg. For Websphere server, the HEAD request is allowed, so the SVG is displayed. But in WebLogic server, the HEAD request received 403 Forbidden which prevent GET request.

I have googled and look into WebLogic online document, but fail to find any info to configure WebLogic server to allow HEAD request. Does anyone have any experience relate to this issue?

Comment: This HEAD request before GET request only occurs in IE browser, in Chrome or Firefox, GET request is submitted directly. We are testing on WebLogic 12C.

Comment: it turns out we have a security constraint set in web.xml to prevent HEAD request. Websphere may be ignore that security constraint to allow HEAD request.

Comment: Instead of commenting on your question, please edit your question - it will help other users with similar problems and users that can help answer.